# php POST variable with headers

Tags: php, post, header, get

This is the code:

```
header("Location: checkout/transactionCompleted.php?id=".$transactionId);
```

Then I use `$_GET['id']` to get the value. So far so good.

**Question**: How can I do that by POSTING the variable instead and without using session??

Thanks,

George

Comment: Build a form, fill it, submit it using JavaScript. No other way

Comment: Why don't you want to use a session?

Comment: That's not good practice. The server should normally only respond to a POST with a GET redirect so that you don't have back button and refresh issues.

Comment: Also, you can use a cookie to store the transaction id as well.

Comment: @Abdullah Jibaly. Which is not a good solution? using $_SESSION or using $_GET?

Comment: It's not a good solution to try to emulate the server sending you to a page using POST. I'm referring to this pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 3):

```
$post_data = 'id='.$transactionId;
$content_length = strlen($post_data);

header('POST checkout/transactionCompleted.php');
header('Host: localhost');
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
header('Content-length: ' . $content_length);
header('');
header($post_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
$http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$http_request .= $req;
```

I think that you have to fill such form, and then send it.