# php conditional internal redirect after script execution

Tags: php, redirect

I have 3 files index.php, search.php, test.php

test.php contains a script just for execution doesn't display anything
I want user to automatically redirect (without delay, without displaying anything) from test.php (after execution of test.php) to where they came from

like this

index.php -> test.php ---> index.php

search.php?q=searchterm -> test.php ---> search.php?q=searchterm

I'm new to php so help anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "redirect" is implemented by sending HTTP request.
You have to make sure that no output was before sending headers.

```
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: '.$location);
```

where `$location = 'http://yoursite.com/destination.php';` for example.
You can also send headers with GET or POST parameters if you want. See [php POST variable with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300081/php-post-variable-with-headers)

Comment: that would not work it redirects to only single page (if I entered index.php doesn't matter where the user came from it just redirect to index.php)
I need redirection to the previous page (if came from index.php then redirect to index.php, if came from search.php then redirect to search.php)
header ('Location: '.$location); works but I need conditional redirect

Comment: Then use `$location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` but make sure it's not empty

Answer (score 0):

use 
header( "refresh:3;url=any page you want" );

Comment: You should describe more clearly how to solve the problem, and please format code appropriately.